# Laravel Model Create method returns incomplete fields model instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am having an issue retrieving my model data after insertion. Below is a sample code in which **User model** has already its `$fillable` containing all needed attributes (`id` and `state` attributes as extras to the below ones).

```
$values = ['firstname' => 'Nick', 'lastname' => 'King', 'gender' => 'male' ];
$createdUser = User::create( $values );
```

Here is the migration code :

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname', 60);
        $table->string('lastname', 60);
        $table->string('gender', 6);
        $table->string('state', 20)->default('inactive');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

When sending back the `$createdUser` as **JSON**, I noticed that the `state` attribute doesn't exists.
It does exists in the migration *having a default value* and also in the model `$fillable` but not in the `$hidden` attribute. 
So what's wrong?

Is that a bug for **not having fields inserted with their default values** in the returned model or it's just the way Laravel works.

Comment: Can you share your actual model?

Comment: Ah, looks like [that's how Laravel works](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21449). Just hit the database again with a query. Think, for example, if you had an auto-incremented value. Only the database can track that -- Laravel can't -- so you'd have to hit the database twice, one for insertion, one for that column. With `::create`, Laravel only knows the columns you explicitly define in `$values`.

Comment: I think this is generally only an issue when creating a record for an API, where the data is returned as `JSON`. Couple approaches would be 1) hit the database again after `::create()` to sync `$createdUser` with it's DB counterpart, or 2) in your app, chain a call after your create call to something like `getUser()`, so you're pulling the User from the database.

Comment: `$createdUser()->fresh()` will update the Model with the latest values from the database. This should include the default values for status.

Comment: Please, provide your model and also your migration.

Comment: @ShengSlogar , there is something I don't understand in your opinion. If Laravel can't track that, so, how is it able to get back in the model the **autoincremented id field**?

Comment: The question was edited for **migration code** accordingly to your request @HCK

Comment: By the way @Peter , your idea works but hmm! is not that great. Using the `->fresh()` method will be adding one more **SQL** query to others. 
What I finally did is adding `state` field in the query with its default value. Don't you think that it will be better this way reducing amount of queries?

Comment: OK, looking a bit deeper, you should be able to set a default value on your `User` model by including: `protected $attributes = ['state' => 'inactive'];` ... this should give you a default without hitting the DB an additional time.

Comment: Hi @Peter, Your workaround did the trick. Thank you! Can you post answer so that I can mark as solution?

Comment: @CfassKing Glad it worked for you. I've put the info into an answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to give default values on your Models is to add an `$attributes` property to your `Model` classes:

```
protected $attributes = ['state' => 'inactive'];
```

This should set the default values on the `Model` instance when you create a new model without having to hit the database again after you create it to get the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

The enum field should have predefined values:

> $table->enum(‘state’, [‘active’, ‘inactive’])->default(‘inactive’);

I would also store gender the same way.

Comment: The question was already edited. It was my bad. The `state` field here has a String type. Thanks.

Comment: I know, but you should store it as enum. Why you store it as string?

Comment: In fact, I do use **enum** but just for this post, to make it simple, I've choosen to do it this way.